# App crashes while adding ?attr/colorControlNormal to a view

Tags: android, android-theme, android-attributes

I'm using ?attr/colorControlNormal in a view for divider.

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorControlNormal"/>
```

When i run my app in android 10 it works fine. But if i run it on android 7 or below app crashes with error

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/secondary_text_material_light.xml from drawable resource ID #0x1060126
```

Also same thing goes when I use `?attr/colorSurface` or `?attr/colorOnSurface`.

I'm using these attributes because they will work for both Day and Night Theme.
But I don't know why it is happening, any ideas...

Comment: have you tried with `"?android:attr/...`?

Comment: tried, but getting the same error again.

Comment: Is `colorControlNormal` a color or a drawable ?

Comment: Is this an attribute set by a Material theme, which you are not using yet?

Comment: I have the same problem and can't figure it out